# Different bindings for the Same Contract

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a wcf service with operation contracts as below.

```
[OperationContract]       
bool IsUserAvailable(string userName);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "CreateUser?userId={userId}")]
bool CreateUser(string userId);
```

Note one is defined with webInvoke attribute. I have 2 applications that consume these methods. application 1 calls createUser method through http web request and application 2 ( wcf client ) directly calles IsUserAvailable .  If I try to define both basic http binding and webhttpBinding as in the web.config below - I run into issues.(A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://localhost:xxxx/BookStore.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.)

```
  <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BookStore.IBook" address=""></endpoint>

  <endpoint address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
            contract="BookStore.IBook" />

  <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

My question is - How can I have different bindings for the same contract without running into issues. If I don't specify basichttp binding, I get the error ( no endpoint listening)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have differing addresses - webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding are (as you'd expect) both on the http scheme so you need to differentiate the two endpoints by their address.

Comment: Solved. The address attribute needs to be unique if defining different bindings for the same endpoint. Assigned address ="SOAP" for http binding and it worked.